# vim:tw=78:ts=2:sw=2:expandtab:ft=help:norl:

Tags: vim, markdown

This line appears at the bottom of a .txt file (in the documentation of a vim plugin), and I've seen it recently in some other places:

```
vim:tw=78:ts=2:sw=2:expandtab:ft=help:norl:
```

What does it mean? I've found that is some kind of markdown but I cannot find the whole documentation for it. I would like to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

It's [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) options.

It's basically a way to set options for a specific file, eg. indent policy.

Se `:help modeline`

```
                    *modeline* *vim:* *vi:* *ex:* *E520*
There are two forms of modelines.  The first form:
    [text]{white}{vi:|vim:|ex:}[white]{options}

[text]      any text or empty
{white}     at least one blank character (<Space> or <Tab>)
{vi:|vim:|ex:}  the string "vi:", "vim:" or "ex:"
[white]     optional white space
{options}   a list of option settings, separated with white space or ':',
        where each part between ':' is the argument for a ":set"
        command (can be empty)
```